# Spotify web API display output when in function

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am having an issue with displaying my output, which is the top nth songs of the nth year.

This code does not display output when in a defined function, but it does display the output I want when it is not in a function.

```py
#function 2 using web api of spotify to display top music by popularity by year.

import spotipy
import pandas as pd
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="________", client_secret="_________")
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
      
def Spotify_func():
    
    artist_name = []
    track_name = []
    track_popularity = []
    artist_id = []
    track_id = []
    y= input ("Enter year: ")
    for i in range(0,1000,50):
        track_results = sp.search(q=y, type='track', limit=50,offset=i)
        for i, t in enumerate(track_results['tracks']['items']):
            artist_name.append(t['artists'][0]['name'])
            artist_id.append(t['artists'][0]['id'])
            track_name.append(t['name'])
            track_id.append(t['id'])
            track_popularity.append(t['popularity'])
    import pandas as pd
    num= input("display top: ")

    
    track_df = pd.DataFrame({'artist_name' : artist_name, 'track_name' :track_name , 'track_popularity' : track_popularity, })
    print(track_df.shape)
    track_df.sort_values(by=['track_popularity'], ascending=False)[['track_name', 'artist_name','track_popularity']].head(int(num))


Spotify_func()
```

here is my call for the main program

```
elif option =="2":
    print ("Using spotify web api search for the year and the most popular music and artist of that year.")
    while True:
        inp= input("\nEnter option \n 1. Enter the year to check for top artists \n 2. Use data visualization for the top 10 song\n \n")
        if inp == "1":
            Spotify_func()
```

i am having no output here but it works already in the defined function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `return` statement in your function. The last line of your function should be:

```py
return track_df.sort_values(by=['track_popularity'], ascending=False)[['track_name', 'artist_name','track_popularity']].head(int(num))
```